# Find the eigenvalues of T and an ordered basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Find the eigenvalues of T and an ordered basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ is a diagonal matrix.

$V = P_1(R)$ and $T(ax+b) = (-6a + 2b) x + (-6a + b)$

First i gave the canonical basis of $V$ that is $\{ 1,x \}$ then i tried to find the matrix associated with this basis, i.e, compute $T(1)$ and $T(x)$ :

$T(1 = 0x + 1) = (-6a + b) $,
$T(x = 1x + b ) = (-6a + 2b) x + (-6a + b)$

but i stuck here is that correct this?

I know how to find the eigenvalues and then the respective eigenvectors  and finally find the diagonal matrix but here how to find this matrix associated to the canonical basis of polynomials of one variable ($V$) please help me here and then i can do the rest, plz and ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's represent $T$ as a matrix acting on $P_1(\mathbb{R})$, with ordered basis $(1,x)$. Then, we can compute that $T(1) = 2x + 1$ and $T(x) = -6x -6$, so the matrix of $T$ is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -6 \\
2 & -6 \end{pmatrix},
$$
since the first column is the vector $T(1)$ and the second column is the vector $T(x)$, both with respect to the basis $(1,x)$. Now, we can go about diagonalizing this matrix as we normally would: it has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -3$ and $\lambda_2 = -2$ with eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ respectively. It follows that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 0 \\
0 & -2 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -6 \\
2 & -6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
That is, the above diagonal matrix is the matrix of the linear transformation $T$ with respect to the ordered basis $\left( \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot 1, \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot x \right)$.

Comment: really ty for the answer thanx!!!!!